# how much wood, dung, hyssop, and red string can be added to the red heifer fire?

Tags: parah-adumah

The Torah says to add these items to the fire when burning the red heiffer. To maximize the ash yeild, can I put in enormous quantities of this non-rare material?

Comment: Added dung? huh?? Where does it say that in the Torah?

Comment: Adding to what @DoubleAA asked, the verse says to burn **its** dung. I assume all of the dung emanating from the animal. There's no indication about adding extra, and, perhaps, doing that would be prohibited.

Comment: Bemidbar 19:6 seems to indicate the 3 items (except for the dung) in singular form. I.e. 1 piece (don't know what size) of cedar wood, 1 *tola'at shani* and 1 hyssop. There is no indication in that verse or anywhere else that the purpose is to maximize ash output or even that one may be permitted to do so. Perhaps the volume of ash, then would be primarily caused by the size of the cow, and perhaps the amount of dung.

Comment: https://www.zoharamar.org.il/wp-content/uploads/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F-PDF.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mishnah in Parah 4:4 says that you can keep adding wood until the cow turns to ash.  The implication is that you can add as much as you want.

Comment: Is this only wood, or does it include any of the other mentioned items?

Comment: @DanF No it's just wood, but if the goal is to increase the amount of ashes there would be no point adding more of the other things when you can just add wood.

Comment: If you have no extra wood, but still want to increase the ash volume, are you allowed to add any of the other items, or is this prohibited?